# Which one is better rebase local or remote to keep remote master up-to-date?

Tags: git, bitbucket

We are using bit bucket as a version control tool. I am working in a team and I want to create a new feature in the project. So, I have checked out my new feature branch(name: feature/add_product) which is keeping track of `origin/master`. I have done with my feature so I did commit and push it in the remote repository. I have created a pull request and now it has been approved.

Now I have one situation here before approval of my PR someone in the team has merged 1 commit to the remote master branch. So, my remote feature branch is 1 commit behind and 1 commit ahead of the remote master.

My question is which one is better between the following two cases to make my feature branch up to date both locally and remotely?

1. Come back to the feature branch of the local repository and do

   ```
   git fetch && git rebase origin/master
   ```

   Then

   ```
   git push origin feature/add_product -f
   ```

   This will keep
2. Go to the pull request page which I had raised a pull request to merge the feature branch to remote master and click on the git rebase button and then after rebase click on the git merge button.

   Once your remote master branch is up to date then come back to the local feature branch and keeps it up-to-date.

   ```
   git fetch && git rebase origin/master
   ```

Comment: What do you mean by "which is keeping track of origin/master"? When you push your branch does it push to `origin/master`? This sounds like a mistake. Instead you should push to `origin/feature/add_product` until your feature is finished and then merge into master.

Comment: And what do you mean by "Go to the feature branch of the remote repository"? How exactly would you do this?

Comment: `git checkout -b feature/add_product origin/master` I guess Using this command it will keep track of `origin/master`.

Comment: Sorrry for the second case, I'll try to update it more accurately

Comment: @John yes it will do the same think but my question which one is better? does the second approach will do extra work than the first approach?

Comment: "I guess Using this command it will keep track of origin/master" That is incorrect. The `git checkout` command you show creates a new branch at the same place as the current `origin/master`. From there on, these are two independent branches. `feature/up_stream` will not "keep track of" `origin/master`.

Comment: " Go to the pull request page which I had raised a pull request to merge the feature branch to remote master and click on the git rebase button" This is a webpage on BitBucket, right?

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik That's interesting. I've never seen a rebase button in my PRs on BitBucket. I've only ever rebased locally, either from the command line or with the git functionality in my IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1 is exactly what I do when rebasing my feature branch onto master.

Case 2 sounds like you perform a rebase on the BitBucket website then do it from the command line. This is problematic because each action will result in entirely different commits. If you add more changes to your local feature branch and try to push, you will get an error.

This happens because a commit is not only the contents of the textual changes but also contains metadata, such as the author's name and email address **as well as the time that the commit occurred**. By rebasing on BitBucket and then again locally, you will have two differing histories because the timestamps on commits with corresponding changes will not be the same.

With that said, you must ensure that the histories are the same in your local repo and in the BitBucket repo. One way to do this is with Option 1. If you use the the rebase button on your PR then you can use `git fetch && git reset --hard origin/feature/add_product` to reset your local branch to the remote tracking branch. **Beware that `git reset --hard` throws away all local changes that are not yet committed.** This is not recoverable using git alone. It also moves your current branch to point to another commit which effectively throws away the current branch's history. This is recoverable but still be cautions with using it.

Comment: When you click vertical dots menu near git merge button there is multiple options like git rebase git squash.

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik Huh...I don't have that. Sounds like a nice feature. My PRs have the following buttons: Request changes, Merge, and then a hamber menu (virtical dots) with more options, but none of them include "git rebase" or "git squash".

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik Be careful. If you are talking about "merge strategies", this button will merge the PR into master and close it. Only do this when your feature branch is final.

Comment: Yes understood, case 2 is problematic if I made some changes to my local feature branch then it will be difficult to push it on the remote feature branch. I got my answer thanks buddy

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik To clarify, the problematic part in Case 2 is using the rebase button on BitBucket as well as `git rebase` locally. If instead of `git rebase` you use the command that I show in the most recent version of my answer, you can use the rebase button on BitBucket (assuming that button doesn't close the PR and do something with master instead of the feature branch).